# I am trying to get year from selection but getting undefined in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get a year from the selection option when I select any year and then I am getting undefined on alert please help me thanks.

**html view**

```
  <label for="opt11" class="option">Select Year</label>
          @foreach($years as $year)
          <input class="selectopt" name="test1" type="radio" id="opt{{$year->year}}">
          <label for="opt{{$year->year}}" data-year="{{$year->year}}" class="option text-box year"  data-maxlength=28>
          <p>{{$year->year}}</p>
          </label>
```

**jquery script**

```
  $('.selectopt').on('change', function() {
    
      let year = $(this).data('year');
    
        alert(year); getting unfined
   
    });
```

Comment: Why not set the year in `value` for each radio... then use `this.value`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` in your *change* handler is the radio button, *not* the `<label>` element.

Try this instead

```js
let year = $(`label[for="${this.id}"]`).data("year")
```

or even this

```js
$(this).next("label.option").data("year")
```

---

I can't see any reason to use a data-attribute when you could just use the radio button's `value`

```html
<input
  class="selectopt" 
  name="test1" 
  type="radio" 
  id="opt{{ $year->year }}"
  value="{{ $year->year }}"
>
```

```js
$(".selectopt").on("change", function(e) {
  const year = this.value
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to pass the data through the input tag, not through the label. Then it will look like the following code structure-

```
<input class="selectopt" name="test1" type="radio" id="opt{{$year->year}}" data-year="{{$year->year}}">
```

And, I hope it will work fine. thanks